# Bespoke JCE Provider on IBM AIX

Tags: java, cryptography, aix, jce

I'm writing a new JCE Provider for a client, because I need to expose some custom Cipher. After extending `CipherSpi` and `ProviderSpi`, I'm ready to build. So I asked the client which version of Java they were targeting. They responded with:

```
# java -version
java version "1.6.0"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build pap3260sr9fp2-20110627_03(SR9 FP2)) IBM J9 VM (build 2.4, JRE 1.6.0 IBM J9 2.4 AIX ppc-32 jvmap3260sr9-20110624_85526 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled) J9VM - 20110624_085526 JIT  - r9_20101028_17488ifx17
GC   - 20101027_AA)
JCL  - 20110530_01
#
```

Damn. So they are using IBM Java 1.6.0 in an AIX machine.

I have written most of the bespoke JCE Provider to support the functionality required (using the [How to Implement a Provider](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/crypto/HowToImplAProvider.html) guide), extending `ProviderSpi` and `CipherSpi` abstract classes from the `com.sun.*` packages. Do I need to get the IBM Java JDK and extend the abstract classes from `com.ibm.*`? Or can I just get my JCE provider JAR signed using my Sun-rooted Java code-signing certificate, and plop it straight in to the right place on the AIX system? (One of these is daft, but I don't know which).

I just don’t know enough about JCE / JVM flavours to know if I now need an IBM-rooted Java code-signing certificate (if one even exists), or if the Sun-rooted signature is sufficient?

Comment: I guess that your aren't using com.sun.* packages, but java.security and javax.crypto

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both Oracle (Sun) and IBM JREs are using each other certificates to verify provider signature. So if you have provider signed using certificate from Sun **it will work on IBM JRE**. So yes - IBM-rooted Java code-signing certificate exists (the CA exists, it's almost impossible to obtain the cert even if you are inside IBM), but **the Sun-rooted signature is sufficient**. Your cryptographic provider will work on IBM JRE. You don't need to use any `com.ibm` package. Moreover it is possible to bypass provider signature requirement: [Java HotSpot Cryptographic Provider signature verification issue](http://java.zacheusz.eu/provider-signature-verif-vuln-2/273/)

## Detailed explanation

### 1. Certificates

The provider certificate verification is done by internal Java 1.6 JCE classes.

- in Oracle `javax.crypto.SunJCE_b#a(X509Certificate c)`
- in IBM `javax.crypto.b#a(X509Certificate c)`

The CA certificates used to verify signatures are stored in class files. In Oracle JVM as plain strings. IBM is doing this smarter - the certificate strings are obscured. To unobscure them you should use this piece of code:

```
final char[] key = {0x5f, 38, 3, 111, 110};

char[] decode(final char[] input) {
    final char[] output = new char[input.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < output.length; i++) {
        output[i] = (char)(input[i] ^ key[i % 5]);
    }
    return output;
}
```

So in the IBM Java 1.6 you can find CA code signing certificates:

- `CN = JCE Code Signing CA, OU = Java Software Code Signing, O = Sun Microsystems Inc, L = Palo Alto, S = CA, C = US`
- `CN = JCE Code Signing CA, OU = IBM Code Signing, O = IBM Corporation, C = US`
- `CN = JCE Code Signing - Framework, OU = IBM Code Signing, O = IBM Corporation, C = US`

### 2. Base provider classes

You should extend `java.security.Provider` class. For example `com.ibm.crypto.provider.IBMJCE` bundled with IBM JRE does it. (AFAIK there is no `ProviderSpi` class.) You should use `javax.crypto.CipherSpi` class too. For example `com.ibm.crypto.provider.DESCipher` from IBM provider does it.

Comment: Not sure why you've got a down-vote for this, looks like a helpful answer. While my colleague belial was out the office, we've done some further testing on IBM Java and can confirm that Sun JCE provider works nicely on IBM Java. Nice to understand the root cause.

Comment: Maybe somebody doesn't understand my response. So since you confirmed it you can mark my answer as correct ;)

Comment: Only belial can do that. And I'm going to be mean and hold out on the bounty, just in case a staggeringly brilliant four-page answer arrives in the next day or so :-)

Comment: OK :) I'll expand my answer soon with the details.